# SSL errors on WCF standalone application (SSL used for securing transport only)

Tags: wcf, ssl, windows-server-2003

I have a wcf application (standalone service self hosted). This is NOT hosted in IIS and hosting it in IIS is not an option.
The service exposes a WCF service. I know that the service contract works because it works with HTTP as transport.
Now, I need to move to https. The intent is to secure the transport only. Client authentication is not required as we assume that anybody connecting to service is within the network.
After making changes to app.config to access httpsTransport in  and updating the URLs across board, i started working on associating cert with port. The explanation is in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733791.aspx I followed instructions under section "To bind an SSL certificate to a port number". This worked nicely within the local machine. Note that root certificate and development certificate is generated using makecert.exe
When i host the same service in Windows server 2003, all hell breaks loose. The clients do not even get to see the endpoint (note that it's not firewalled as http works). I have followed the steps outlined in the document mentioned above (using httpcfg.exe). This does not work. OpenSSL mentions that server did not provide a certificate.

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Did your server start correctly on 2003?

Did you configure your client to look for the server's certificate like following snippet? Pleaes check you didn't mistype the name of the certficate.

```
<endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="DirectConnection"
            behaviorConfiguration="Behavior"
            contract="AContract"
            name="ServiceContract" > 
    <identity>
      <dns value="ServerCertificate.Com" />
    </identity>
```

Comment: The serer started correctly. The service is up and running (no exception and eventlog entries). Let me try the server certificate changes. BTW, i am using basicHttpBinding and not netTcpBinding.

Comment: The binding looks like this. <binding name="bindingName"> <textMessageEncoding /> <sslStreamSecurity requireClientCertificate="false"/> <httpsTransport /> </binding>

Comment: it should be the same, try to add <identity>. BTW, can you put here client's binding here?

Comment: I don't have control over the kind of client that will connect. It could be java for a c++ application that just open connection to the port and then starts sending soap requests. Having said that, I will create a client in .net and post the client binding in some time.

Comment: I investigated this further and realized that this is not wcf issue. So client binding does not solve this issue. I plan to start another thread asking question differently.

Comment: Turned out that using self signed certificates could not be used on windows 2003 server (this particular instance). I am guessing it's being treated as untrusted cert. Once we got the official certs, things just worked with no changes.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out that using self signed certificates could not be used on windows 2003 server (this particular instance). I am guessing it's being treated as untrusted cert. Once we got the official certs, things just worked with no changes.